# Vim Scripting: Count lines that match expression, and fold

Tags: vim, plugins, scripting, loops, folding

I am currently developing a plugin for Vim for managing checklists.

I am currently using ":setlocal foldmethod=indent" in a syntax file to handle all of the folding within each checklist document. However, I'd like to create a function for folding that is more flexible, and will not rely on the indentation of the line to determine whether or not it is folded.

Here is an example checklist:

```
+ Parent
  * Child
  * Child
  * Child
```

When a user presses `<leader>`vv on the "+ Parent" line, it fold the lines underneath it because they are indented one level. The problem with this is that the foldmethod sticks around for other buffers and folds lines that do not need to be folded.

Here is how I've thought of handling it so far:

```
function! FoldLines()
  let l:line = getline(line(".") + 1)

  " If next line is a child
  if match(l:line, '^\s*\*') >= 0

  " Loop until blank line is found, and store line numbers in a list
  endif

  " Select lines from list and fold
endfunction
```

I don't know how to handle the loop and folding. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Well, karategeek6's solution works to some degree, but I failed to mention that my plugin also toggles checklist items.

Example:

```
+ Parent
  × Child - Toggled
  * Child - Standard
```

I may be wrong, but I don't think that foldexpr will be able to handle lines with both * and × at the beginning.

I've tried:

```
set foldexpr=strlen(substitute(substitute(getline(v:lnum),'\\s','',\"g\"),'[^[*|×]].*','',''))
```

but that doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: Where you have put `[^[*|×]]`, try `[^*x]`.

Comment: @Johnsyweb,

Thanks. This works a little better, but for some reason it doesn't like when the first line after my + Parent line is checked off. It will fold if the first child is untoggled, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems like I found a solution. I ended up using this:

```
setlocal foldlevel=0
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=FoldLevel(v:lnum)

function! FoldLevel(linenum)
  let linetext = getline(a:linenum)
  let level = indent(a:linenum) / 4
  if linetext =~ '^\s*[\*|×]'
    let level = 20
  endif
  return level
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you want it to fold by expression.  According to the [user manual](http://vim.dindinx.net/vim7/html/usr_28.txt.php#28.8), in fold by expression, you use an expression to set the fold level of every line.  The user manual gives an example which I think can be adapted to your needs.

```
:set foldmethod=expr
:set foldexpr=strlen(substitute(substitute(getline(v:lnum),'\\s','',\"g\"),'[^*].*','',''))
```

You can read more on the example at the user manual, but in a nutshell, it will set the fold level equal to that of the number of leading '*', irrespective of whitespace.

Hopefully this is either exactly what you were looking for, or can point you in the right direction.  The key aspect to remember in folding by expression is that you are deciding the fold level of each line, rather than which lines to fold.

Comment: Thanks! This is just about perfect, but I'll check out the manual as well and see where that leads me.